# How to get the first value from an undetermined group

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

Can anyone help me with this, I'm using Athena, and I was looking for some solution, well Athena doesn't support variables, so how can I fill `sessao` as well?
[image]

Comment: You should put your current query in the question -- as text, using "code" formatting, _not_ an embedded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming empty values mean nulls - you can use `last_value` window function with `ignore nulls` option:

```sql
WITH dataset(value, ts) AS (
    values ('a', timestamp '2012-08-08 01:00'),
        (null, timestamp '2012-08-08 01:01'),
        (null, timestamp '2012-08-08 01:02'),
        ('b', timestamp '2012-08-08 02:00'),
        (null, timestamp '2012-08-08 02:01')
)


SELECT coalesce(value, last_value(value) ignore nulls over (order by ts)) value, ts
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| value | ts |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2012-08-08 01:00:00.000 |
| a | 2012-08-08 01:01:00.000 |
| a | 2012-08-08 01:02:00.000 |
| b | 2012-08-08 02:00:00.000 |
| b | 2012-08-08 02:01:00.000 |